# Unity 2D Why does my character jump different heights every time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, my jumping is inconsistent, basically, every time i press space the character jumps different heihgts, even when standing still (not moving left, and right), why is that?

here is my code:

```
public bool onGround = false;
public float JumpHeight;
public Rigidbody2D gravidade;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}



// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (onGround == true)
    { 
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            gravidade.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpHeight * Time.deltaTime), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
         
        }
    }
}
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D outro)
{
    if (outro.gameObject.CompareTag("ground"))
    {
        onGround = true;
    }
}
void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D outro)
{
    if (outro.gameObject.CompareTag("ground"))
    {
        onGround = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: because the time delta is varying - you're applying a one-time force, not a continuous movement, so i _guess_ you should just leave out the delta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't multiply by delta time when applying a one-time force.

Answer (score 0):

`Time.deltaTime` is the time completion time in seconds since the last frame. Check the [documetation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

This time is not constant. MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate uses fixedDeltaTime instead of deltaTime, this fixedDeltaTime and the [FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) is usually used for physics and it is quite an advanced topic.

Use a [constant value](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const) instead of the `Time.deltaTime` to have always the same jump height.

Comment: Note that you can and according to the docs, should use deltaTime in the FixedUpdate as well because on a device where the FixedUpdates simply cannot be executed sufficiently fast enough (or during lagspikes which occasionally occur on any machine), deltaTime will adapt correctly while fixedDeltaTime is literally constant (except for user-defined influence by timeScale). However you are right, like @Piggy said up there too, one-time forces should not be scaled.

Answer (score -1):

It is different becuase it's calculated off of deltaTime, which is incosistent (time between two rendered frames if i'm not wrong), and it yields a slightly different value every time, which combined with multiplication has a bigger deviation from an average.
Hope i helped to clarify this, cheers!